# Django Date Filter Weirdness

Tags: django, date, filter

I have some date filtering in django that I just can't see what's wrong.

I have a model with this field:

```
date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank = True, null=True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

I then select all data

```
users = UserDetails.objects.all()
```

I have 2 rows in the database and two object returned

```
>>> users
[<UserDetails: UserDetails object>, <UserDetails: UserDetails object>]

>>> users[0]
<UserDetails: UserDetails object>
```

I can see each objects date_of_birth value

```
>>> users[0].date_of_birth
datetime.date(1971, 9, 28)
```

However any filter I try always fails?

```
>>> users = users.filter(date_of_birth__year >= 1970)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'date_of_birth__year' is not defined

>>> users = users.filter(date_of_birth == datetime.date(1971, 9, 28))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'date_of_birth' is not defined

>>> users = users.filter(date_of_birth == '1971-09-28')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'date_of_birth' is not defined
```

Can anyone help explain what's wrong here?
I'm at a loss.

Thanks.

Comment: Arg .. having two '==' breaks it. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't filter using the comparison operators. What you're doing is actually passing a keyword argument to the `filter` method. To filter based on equality, simply do:

```
users = users.filter(date_of_birth=datetime.date(1971, 9, 28))
```

To filter using greater than or equals, use:

```
users = users.filter(date_of_birth__year__gte=1970)
```

That is, you append `__gte` to the keyword argument.

You can also filter on less than or equals (`date_of_birth__year__lte`), less than (`date_of_birth__year__lt`), or greater than (`date_of_birth__year__gt`).

Comment: In Django 1.4, using `__lt`, `__gt`, etc. doesn't work with `__year`, `__month`, and `__day`. There's a ticket for adding that functionality: [link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10911).